# Jest, toClick() fails upon <i> tag with Puppeteer

Tags: jestjs, automated-tests, puppeteer

I am trying to simulate a button click upon an ellipsis:

```
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-ellipsis-v context-button"> ... </i>
```

using this code:

```
    await expect(page).toClick(".fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-ellipsis-v context-button");
```

But this error pops up every time i run this test:

```
TimeoutError: Element .fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-ellipsis-v not found
```

I am simulating other clicks upon divs and spans and everything works fine, any idea why this is not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector has the wrong syntax, see [this link for how to select elements using multiple classes](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/).

```
await expect(page).toClick(".fa.fa-lg.fa-fw.fa-ellipsis-v.context-button");
```

Comment: Great! I always used to forget the first dot

Comment: I just didn't realise that the space in between the different classes was not needed :)